# A cyclotomic integer ring which is not norm-Euclidean

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $A=\mathbb Z[\zeta_{32}]$ the cyclotomic integer ring for $n=32$.

Any one of you understand why this  ring is not norm-Euclidean?

Reza Ahktar wrote a proof due to Lenstra as you know. But I do not fully undertand.

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to format questions/answers using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Comment: Well, I don't know...and I know both Reza and Lenstra. Would you mind putting a link to that paper or whatever?

Comment: I`m sorry  here is a link....http://calico.mth.muohio.edu/reza/research/seniorthesis/seniorthesis.pdf

Comment: A proof starting on page 28

Comment: Please explain which part of the proof you don't understand.

Comment: I'm José Camarillo and this is my new username. I don't understand form the last two lines of page 28.